# clearInterval is not clearing setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I have made a memory game with a timer that start at 10 minutes and counts down every second to 0. This function is only called once and has the following setInterval function:

```
game.countdown = setInterval(function() {
                    if(game.timeLeft <= 0){
                        gameEnded = true;
                    }

                    if(!gameEnded){
                        // lower one second
                        game.timeLeft--;

                        var timespan = document.querySelector('.timeleft');

                        var minutes =  pad(Math.floor((game.timeLeft / 60)),2 );
                        var newSeconds =  pad(Math.floor(game.timeLeft - (minutes * 60)),2 );

                        function pad(num, size) {
                            var s = num+"";
                            while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
                            return s;
                        }

                        var niceTime = minutes + ":" + newSeconds;

                        timespan.innerHTML = niceTime;

                        // Then alter time bar on .innertimer
                        // Calculate percentage starting at 0%
                        var percentageDone = (Math.floor((10*60 - game.timeLeft) / (10*60) * 10000) / 100);
                        $(".timer").css({"background": "-webkit-linear-gradient(left, white " + percentageDone + "%, green " + percentageDone + "%)"});
                    }
                }, 1000);
```

I store the setInterval in object game under variable name countdown. When the game is ended I call another function that has the clearInterval:

```
clearInterval(game.countdown);
```

Then when it goes to the next level it calls the setInterval function again and stores it again in game.countdown. But now for every second it takes 2 seconds. The next level 3 seconds. You can see there are multiple setInterval's at work because it's not done at the same time.

Hope someone can really help me out debugging this problem.

Comment: Are you sure `clearInterval` is being called? Might be helpful to see the logic around when that takes place.

Comment: I added an alert the line before the clearInterval and the clearInterval is being called. If I do alert("game.countdown: " + JSON.stringify(game.countdown, null, 4)); then in the first level it gives undefined. It's before the setInterval. Then the second level it gives 1 and the third level it gives 5.

Comment: is it possible setInterval is initially being triggered twice so that when clearInterval is called it's only calling clear one of the intervals?  you can test that by throwing some console.log() trace statements within the setInterval callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done to work around the issue is the following. The interval is only being called if the following is true:

```
if (undefined == game.countdown){
```

This way if there is a countdown defined it's calling it again. And since I'm storing the game.timeLeft not in the function itself I can just refill game.timeLeft.